# How to get the URL value

Tags: php, url

```
www.example.com/aacc
```

I want to get aacc from url in `index.php`. But it never redirects to index page.

It shows only:

> The requested URL /aacc was not found on this server.

Comment: Please accept an answer, that's how this site works ;) If you don't know what I mean, please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

This is because the webserver is looking for a directory or file named `aacc`. To change this, you'll need a [Rewrite engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) to turn requests into requests to your root `index.php` file.

There are plenty of resources on [Stackoverflow about Apache's mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mod_rewrite&submit=search).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for a rewrite rule?

If your web server is Apache, you could use something like a [Rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in your Apache configuration:

```
RewriteRule   ^/(.*)    /index.php?what=$1
```

With this, any URL will be converted into `$_GET['what']` in index.php.

I mention Apache because it's so common.  If you're using something else, please specify it in your question.

Comment: Yes I'm using Apache. Thanks a lot Ghoti.